# What is the format of EWS?

Tags: logging, exchangewebservices

I have ews logs coming from my client and I am supposed to parse it in logstash. I am not able to understand the format for ews logs nor I can find some documentation on its log format. I am pasting one of the logs here. I have changed some of the information while keeping the format same. Can anyone please explain to me what each fields mean and what ",,,,," means? or even point to proper documentation will be helpful.

> 2018-09-12T20:26:21.564Z,764e05a7-7adf-4a1b-a32d-32ccb2134947,15,1,1415,2,Unknown,,Negotiate,true,sdfgsdg@asdasd.com,asdasd.com,OC/16.0.8431.2270
>   (Skype for
>   Business),Target=None;Req=Exchange2012/Exchange2013;,192.168.85.52,MPEXMBX2,OCEXMBX1.asdasd.COM,GetStreamingEvents,200,924,,,sdfgsdg@asdasd.com,,,3b4df7c98d6f479b9f662923b0047f0c,b8ddd1b2-cca7-46fa-b77a-3dc67847fa3d,PrimaryServer,LocalTask,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,[C],0,0,0,0,,,1,0,,0,4,0,5,,,SKU=Unknown;App_BeginReq_Start=0;App_BeginReq_End=0;GetHandler_Start=1;RequestHandler=Wcf;GetHandler_End=1;BackEndAuthenticator=WindowsAuthenticator;TotalBERehydrationModuleLatency=0;CSCWTI=0;CSCWTI=0;cpn=RUM_ABR/RUM_ABRC/ABR/APAR/EWS_CE/EWS_CEC/APSRH/APRHE/RUM_AER/RUM_AERC/AER/AERC/;cpv=0/0/0/1/4/5/5/6/6/6/6/6/;MailboxTypeCacheSize=106855;S:AspDispatchLatency.BeginRequest=0;S:ADRS.InclI=1;S:AspDispatchLatency.EndRequest=0;S:ADRS.Check=00;S:ServiceTaskMetadata.WatsonReportCount=0;S:WLM.Bal=300000;S:ServiceTaskMetadata.ServiceCommandBegin=4;S:ServiceTaskMetadata.ServiceCommandEnd=4;S:ActivityStandardMetadata.Component=Ews;S:WLM.BT=Ews;S:EwsMetadata.HttpHandlerGetterLatency=0;Dbl:WLM.TS=5;Dbl:CCpu.T[CMD]=0;Dbl:BudgUse.T[]=1.00339996814728,,,,2018-09-12T20:26:21.557Z,4436,,381836456,383018760,380853_30701_838,380853_30701_838,,,,,,,,,,,,

I want to parse every field and for that I need to know names of each and every field (like client_ip, source_ip, transaction_id etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As for  “, , , , ,” ,  which means search for Exchange servers in one or multiple sites.

The default setting is the current site from the script is running.

You can define multiple sites by using comma seperated.Default which means the site of the machine you are running the script.

Reference:
https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/troubleshooting-exchange-with-logparser-ews-logs/

You can try parsing logs with PowerShell.

Comment: I tried your method but it is not working. log parser is not parsing the logs. I was to parse every field and want to know proper names of each field.